# Android application build failed: Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I have an Android application and I am not able to build successfully.
This is my `gradle.app` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.bioresult.cardio"
        minSdkVersion 28
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }

    }
    //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.5.1'
    final ROOM_VERSION = '1.1.1'
    final DAGGER_VERSION = '2.15'
    final ARCHITECTURE_COMPONENT_VERSION = '1.1.1'
    //noinspection OutdatedLibrary
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'me.hiennguyen.circleseekbar:circleseekbar:1.0.1'
    implementation 'me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.1.7'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v0.9.3'
    implementation 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.1'
    //    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    //    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    //bargraph
    implementation 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    // implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
    //Job Scheduler and MQTT
    implementation 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    //    implementation 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'
    //    implementation 'me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.1.4'
    //    implementation 'com.github.feeeei:CircleSeekbar:v1.1.2'
    implementation project(':speedviewlib')
    implementation 'eo.view:batterymeter:1.1.1'
    //PROVO A COMMENTARE QUESTA LINE ADI CODICE
    //implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation project(':zephyrlib')
    //implementation project(':ecgview')
    //implementation 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.5.3'
    // implementation project(':support')
    //compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    //QUESTO SERVE PER L INVIO DEI CRASH
    //implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
    //COMMENTO QUESTA LINEA DI CODICE
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-bluetooth:1.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1'
    //COMMENTO QUESTA LINEA DI CODICE
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    //COMMENTO QUESTA LINEA DI CODICE
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math:2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.2'
    implementation project(':subsamplinglib')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    //  compile project(path: ':whitelabel')
    implementation files('libs/Jama-1.0.3.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.Abhi347:LumberJack:0.1.0'
    //salvare i dati automaticvamente nelle preferenze del sistema
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'

    //NEXTOME
    //implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0"

    /*
    integrazione da app indiani
    * */
    // RxJava / RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.10'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$ROOM_VERSION"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$ROOM_VERSION"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$ROOM_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.razerdp:AnimatedPieView:1.2.6'
    implementation 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation project(':horizontalcalendar')
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:progressview:1.0.7"
    implementation 'com.henryblue.mxvideoplayer:xvideoplayer:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.HamidrezaAmz:MagicalExoPlayer:1.0.16'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:3.0.3'
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
    implementation 'com.lemmingapex.trilateration:trilateration:1.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the error that I can read from Android console:

```
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies

FAILURE: Build completed with 5 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'android-beacon-library.aar (org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.19.6)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at     
==============================================================================

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'android-beacon-library.aar (org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.19.6)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.LegacyTransformer.transform(LegacyTransformer.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

    
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'android-beacon-library.aar (org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.19.6)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at 
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.LegacyTransformer.transform(LegacyTransformer.java:76)
    at 
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform artifact 'android-beacon-library.aar (org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.19.6)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res}.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.lambda$visitArtifact$1(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\michele.castriotta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.altbeacon\android-beacon-library\2.19.6\c967a0d449bc55e98d768fa096de8733bb2a4926\android-beacon-library-2.19.6.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transformLibrary(Processor.kt:421)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:247)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:113)
    ... 81 more

==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

BUILD FAILED in 10s
98 actionable tasks: 98 executed
```

What can I do to fix them?